# Can Wifi Calling protocol be programmed into FirefoxOS?

Tags: ssl, protocols, network-protocols, gsm, firefox-os

Using TCPdump, when connecting wifi-calling I saw DNS request to snq.t-mobilesgws.com. Then it does some ISAKMP protocol requests, TLSv1, then "ESP" protocol, according to Wireshark.

I'm glad to see it doesn't send the IMEI in plaintext over wifi, but I'm not sure what this protocol is - could it be added to FirefoxOS/Ubuntu-touch for example? Or is this already UMA standard with many mobile OSs?

Comment: In order to implement wifi calling you would have to tap into the phone at a pretty low level, I find it unlikely that the phone OS Would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulating Security Payload is part of IPsec, which you can read more about [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulating_Security_Payload#Encapsulating_Security_Payload) "The main job of ESP is to provide the privacy we seek for IP datagrams by encrypting them." The protocol is only available with IPSec devices. I have to agree with Paul and say that it's extremely unlikely without altering the way the OS communicates.

Comment: In other words, there is no Javascript low-level interface for a user-app to do something like this in FxOS, and UMA is not supported in FirefoxOS itself?

Answer (score 0):

[ISAKMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Security_Association_and_Key_Management_Protocol) (**Internet Security Association and Key Management Protocol**) is a cryptographic protocol, the base protocol of IKE (**Internet key exchange**) which is used to establish a Security Association in the **IPsec** protocol (using **IP Encapsulating Security Payload** (ESP) or **IPSec Authentication Header**(IPsec AH)).

Of course you can develop your own implementation but you need a hard knowledge about the protocols defined in [RFC2408](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2408), [RFC2407](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2407) (for ISAKMP) and [RFC4302](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4302.html) or [RFC4303](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4303.txt) (for IPsec AH or ESP).

All this protocols are defined as Internet Standards for communications, not as UMA, UMA is defined for web-based access management.

Firefox OS (linux based) already implements a [wpa_supplicant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Architecture#wpa_supplicant) daemon that handles connectivity with [WiFi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Architecture#WiFi) so it has no sense develop a custom implementation.

Anyway, if you want to acces the Firefox OS API to connect to a WiFi Network you could not do it because this API is available for [certified applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Security/Application_security#App_Types) only (OEM).

Comment: While you did explain what the various acronyms in the post mean, you did not address the OP question.  They are asking about, essentially, placing a call over wifi.